# No LocaDb SQL Server Express database generated while using EF Code first

Tags: entity-framework

I just follow the instruction to run the program. see the instruction below:

[Code First Migrations instruction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Contents in `Mode.cs`:

```
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure; 

namespace MigrationsDemo 
{ 
    public class BlogContext : DbContext 
    { 
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } 
    } 

    public class Blog 
    { 
        public int BlogId { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
    } 
}
```

Contents in `Program.cs` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MigrationsDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new BlogContext())
            {
                db.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Name = "Another Blog " });
                db.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var blog in db.Blogs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(blog.Name);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey(); 
        }
    }
}
```

The instruction said now run the program and I will see that a `MigrationsCodeDemo.BlogContext` database is created for you.

In the mean time, the instruction said:

If SQL Server Express is installed (included in Visual Studio 2010) then the database is created on your local SQL SErver Express instance (`.\SQLEXPRESS`).

If SQL Server Express is not installed then code-first will try and use LocalDb (`(localdb)\v11.0`) - LocalDb is included with Visual Studio 2012.

But after running this program, I cannot see `MigrationsCodeDemo.BlogContext` having been created in SQL Server Object Explorer, I just see system databases under databases folder, and the command line shows:

```
Another Blog
Another Blog
Another Blog
Another Blog
Press any key to exit...
```

since I run 4 times for this program, so there are 4 lines "Another Blog" appeared in the command line.

Can anyone tell me why the code didn't generate the Local DB for me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you post your web.config?

Comment: no web.config, just a Windows console application

Comment: How about app.config?